# Set Up Sharepoint Site contents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am quite new in sharepoint, I am trying to figure out how to create and rename the site content.

The one in bold on the left of the sharepoint. it is not the subfolder, but the main one in the view all set content section.

Is there anybody have the simlar problems and are able to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

Site Content section is a page of Sharepoint.It shows all the content in the site collection. If you want to build the same as Site Content. You should create a web part that getting all the content(document libraries, lists ...or anything you want to show). Once you have your web part. You can create a new page and insert this web part to this page. You can set the name and the content as you expected.